# If a,b are postive integers, b⁴=96•a³, then find min (a+b)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can you please help me solve this question ;

If $a,b$ are postive integers and,$$b^4=96a³$$ then find minimum value of $a+b$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Hint:  the prime factorization of $96$ is important here.

Comment: One solution is $96^4=96\cdot 96^3$.  Can you divide both sides by anything (perhaps to the power of the lowest common multiple of $3$ and $4$) to leave something which retains the  $b^4=96\cdot a^3$ form?

Comment: $(a,b)=(6,12)$.

Comment: @Atticus can you please write a detailed solution

Comment: It will be a = 6 and b =12, therefore the minimum value of (a+b) = 6+12 = 18.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $3\ |\ b$ and $4\ |\ b$, so $12\ |\ b$, which means the minimum possible positive integer value for $b$ is $12$. Checking this value we get $a = 6$. As $b$ increases, $a$ also increases, so the minimum possible value is:

$$\min(a+b) = 18$$

achieved when $(a,b) = (6,12)$.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's lemma says that if $p$ is prime and $p|c^k$ then $p|c$.

Well, $96 = 2^5*3$ divides $b^4$.  So $3|b^4$ and so $3|b$.  And $2^5|b^4$ so $2|b$.  But if $b = 2m$ then $2^5|2^4m$ so $2|m$ so $4|2m=b$ .  So $12|b$.

and if $b = 12b'$ we have $b^4 = 3^4*2^8b'4 = 2^5*3*a^3$ so $a^3=3^3*2^3b'^4$. so $2|a$ anb $3|a$ and so $6|a$.

And if $a = 6a'$ we get $6^3a'^3 = 6^3b'^4$ and $a'^3 = b'^4$.  We have no further requirements.

So to minimalize $a,b$ we can minimalize $a',b'$ so that $a'^3 = b'^4$ and clearly that is minimalized with $a' = b'=1$.

So $a= 6; b=12$ will be the minimalize $a+b$ (which by $18$) And allow that $b^4= 12^4 = 3^4*2^8=(3*3^5)*3^3*2^3= 96*6^3 = 96a^3$.